# How I can evaluate row data as an array?

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone explain how I evaluate my rows e as an array and not on an individual (row) level? Is this the best way to improve performance?

```
Dim x As Integer, i As Integer, y As Long

Set wsCountry = Sheets("Country Data")
Set wsInstructions = Sheets("Instructions")

LastRow = wsCountry.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 9 To 9
    For i = 9 To LastRow

If wsCountry.Range("E" & i) <> wsInstructions.Range("C" & x) Then
   wsCountry.Range("A" & i & ":P" & i).ClearContents
End If

    Next i

'Delete Blanks
For y = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(y, 3) = "" Then
        Rows(y).Delete
    End If
Next y


'Save workbook AS to FILE

Next x
```

Comment: you can get rid of some of the looping by using a filter and deleting the blank rows in a single pass.  Is it tweaks like that you're after?

Comment: In wsCountry sheet is column A to P the entire row? Also, you want to delete blank rows on what sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 2 AutoFilters:

1. remove rows where column C contains blank values
2. remove rows where column E doesn't contain the value in Instructions sheet cell C9

.

```
Option Explicit

Sub parseRows()
    Dim wsCountry As Worksheet, wsInstructions As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, instructionsVal As String, rowRng As Range

    Set wsCountry = Worksheets("Country Data")
    Set wsInstructions = Worksheets("Instructions")
    instructionsVal = wsInstructions.Range("C9")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastRow = wsCountry.Cells(wsCountry.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rowRng = wsCountry.Range("C8:C" & lastRow)

    With wsCountry.UsedRange    'Filter col 3 (C) - make blanks visible
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
        rowRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    lastRow = wsCountry.Cells(wsCountry.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rowRng = wsCountry.Range("E8:E" & lastRow)

    With wsCountry.UsedRange    'Filter col 5 (E) - values <> instructionsVal
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>" & instructionsVal
        rowRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to autofilter starting with row 8?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine. However, you are asking for optimal performance. That would be done by looping on an array instead of a range, which can get slow when the range is big. It is better to dump the range into an array, like so:

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Sheet1.Range("A1:B10")
```

And looping on the array instead. Since this creates a 2d array, you can elect to loop on one of the dimensions (row) only. I hope I answered your question correctly.